# Why can't I find the CSV file location for "diamonds" dataset in RStudio?

Tags: r, read.csv, readr

I'm a fairly experienced R learner right now(for a beginner level), but I am having trouble getting the diamonds dataset as a csv file from the ggplot2 package.

Although I can see it in the environment pane in RStudio for ggplot2 package, I cannot find its file location as a CSV file to import into my working directory.

When in the environment pane, I have tried to Import Dataset, but it doesn't let me select the diamonds dataset from the Data list.

I have also tried finding it's location in the actual Files pane, going into: /cloud/lib/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2, and then into ggplot2, but cannot find the dataset as CSV there anywhere.

Please help with this. I know the answer must be hiding in plane site...

Comment: What happens when you use `library(ggplot2); data(diamonds)`?

Comment: Thank you for your response! It pops up as a View tab in the R Script pane. But I can't seem to access it as csv to save it to my working directory...

Comment: Does it appear in your Environment panel? What happens when you use `library(ggplot2); data(diamonds); write.csv(diamonds, "mydata.csv")`?

Comment: I do apologize, I know this is must be a super easy element that I just haven't come across in my studying at length. It pops up as a table View tab in the pane with the open tables and R Scripts, but I don't see it's location anywhere, nor that it popped into my working directory.

Comment: (And yes, it is in my environmental pane, but I can't seem to access it other than to view it in a View tab)

Comment: What do you mean by "can't seem to access it"?

Comment: I can't figure out how to access it as a written CSV file to import/move into my working directory, because I can't find the location in the file path, but I can see it in the ggplot2 environmental pane. Does that make sense? I can see it as a table tab where the R Scripts are as well, but I can't for instance, display it as a normal CSV dataset to locate, import and play with in the console for example.

Comment: If you use the code I provided in my second comment, that should write a copy of `diamonds` as a csv to your current working directory. Is that your goal? Since `diamonds` is built into the `ggplot2` package, it doesn't really exist as a csv file, it's just a dataset present in R, but you can write it out as a csv.

Comment: Oh my gosh, amazing! I'm so sorry, I did do that earlier, but amongst my many different attempts at finagling this whole thing, I must have forgotten for one attempt I did change my working directory back to the 4.2 file *facepalm*, where the dataset showed as a CSV at the bottom. Thank you thank you for your time and effort. Trust me, this was driving me nuts! <3

Comment: A second option would be to read the raw CSV file directly from the ggplot2 GitHub repo: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/main/data-raw/diamonds.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the `diamonds` dataset, use the below code.

```
library(ggplot2)
data(diamonds)
```

Additionally, using `write.csv()` will allow you to write a copy of `diamonds` to your current working directory.

```
write.csv(diamonds, "mydata.csv")
```

Comment: It would be nice to include the information that packages don't actually store their data as a CSV when they are deployed. It would be nice if this question might be generally useful for saving any packages dataset as a CSV. There's nothing really special about ggplot/diamonds here.